# q-learning for classification problem

Tags: q-learning

how can I use q-learning for classification problem I see some examples about learning the agent in a game I need to use q-learning for binary classification (classify image if it is for cat or for dog)

Comment: Q learning has a policy. In the agent on agent game, it says if you’re here then you go there. You can think about it like an if then based logic inference engine. It works a little bit like a classification and regression tree, Except that it is iteratively trained so that’s a little bit more like a random forest. Random forests make decent learners for some classification problems.

Comment: @EngrStudent please do you have any code for using q-learning for classification?

Comment: @EngrStudent please do you have any code for using q-learning for classification?

Comment: Like this: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2007/2007.01193.pdf

Comment: @EngrStudent please i want a program (source code) for using q-learning for classification can you help me?

Comment: give a sample problem.  Pick one of the ["time series bakeoff"](https://www.timeseriesclassification.com/) problems that is close to yours, give what measure of goodness you are using, and someone could help with the code.  A code-only question might be more germaine to SO than CV, fwiw.

Comment: @EngrStudent I did not see any code about using q-learning for classification , please help me to find a code that use q-learning for classification

Comment: If you make a well-defined problem then I will make code to do it.  Pick a problem.  Narrow it down.  Also, one-hour turnaround is unreasonable to expect from someone you never met.  Give it a day or two.  Also, Q-learning is old, and slow.  It is not ideal.  It has some serious limits.  You don't find punch-card images for 1970's era programs involving q-learning on the internet.  Personally, I think that they should be retained in a public repository because the 1960's programmers were really really hard working and clever at what they did.

Comment: @EngrStudent i need a code for using q-learning for binary classification like classify email if it is spam or not

Comment: So your training corpus would be like some of [these](https://trec.nist.gov/data/spam.html)?

Comment: @EngrStudent no i did not understand anything from this website please what i need is python program for using q-learning algorithm for binary classification

Answer (score 1):

Q-learning, in operation, looks at the state, finds it in the policy table, and then acts as the policy table dictates.  You can think of it like a hash or a dictionary that says "if state is x then do action y".

Classification is really nominal regression, it makes a continuous value which is mapped to a discrete space via a threshold.

Lets say we have a finite and fixed-order sequence of weighted coins, and we want to predict the next toss with better accuracy than a random guess.  A small example would be a coin "A" that is 99% (mosly heads), followed by "B" that is 60% (mostly heads), finally followed by a coin "C" that is 10% (mostly tails).  We could make a sequence of training data by flipping them and making a long sequence of flips and taking the first three as input and the fourth as output.

There would be three "templates" in the policy.

1. A, B, C $\longrightarrow$ A
2. B, C, A $\longrightarrow$ B
3. C, A, B $\longrightarrow$ C

or

1. (H), (H), (T) $\longrightarrow$ (H)
2. (H), (T), (H) $\longrightarrow$ (H)
3. (T), (H), (H) $\longrightarrow$ (T)

While I can do python, I prefer R.  This is a stats question, not a software question.  If you want a particular language instead of a particular statistical idea, then please ask in SO.

This is a nice vignette on Q-learning in R: [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReinforcementLearning/vignettes/ReinforcementLearning.html)

The following code generates data for training the learner for the rules above.

```
N_flips <- 300

wA <- 0.9
wB <- 0.6
wC <- 0.1

#make raw store
store <- numeric(length = N_flips*3)
count <- 1
for(i in 1:N_flips){
  #flip A
  yA <- rbinom(n = 1, size = 1, prob = wA)
  #flip B
  yB <- rbinom(n = 1, size = 1, prob = wB)
  #flip C
  yC <- rbinom(n = 1, size = 1, prob = wC)
  
  #concatenate result
  store[count] <- yA
  store[count+1] <- yB
  store[count+2] <- yC
  
  count <- count +3
  
}

#format into data frame of state, action, next, reward
coins <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=4, nrow=0))


for(i in 1:(length(store)-5)){
# for(i in 1:2){
  
  #try 10 random actions for each "roll" above
  for(j in 1:10){
    #put first 3 into "state"
    mystate <- paste0(store[i], store[i+1], store[i+2])
    
    #action is guess of next coin
    myaction <- sample(c("h","t"), size=1)
    
    #next state is following 3 rolls
    mynextstate <- paste0(store[i+3], store[i+4], store[i+5])
    
    #if next roll is correct reward 1 else 0
    myreward <- 0
    if(myaction=="h" & store[i+3]==1){
      myreward <- 1
    } 
    if(myaction=="t" & store[i+3]==0){
      myreward <- 1
    } 
    
    #add to coins
    coins <- rbind(coins, c(mystate, myaction, mynextstate, myreward))
  }
}

#formatting 
names(coins) <- c("State", "Action", "NextState", "Reward")
coins$Reward <- as.numeric(coins$Reward)
```

and here is the structure of the data.frame that it outputs

```
> #display coins
> str(coins)
'data.frame':   8950 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ State    : chr  "110" "110" "110" "110" ...
 $ Action   : chr  "h" "t" "h" "t" ...
 $ NextState: chr  "110" "110" "110" "110" ...
 $ Reward   : num  1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 ...
```

Here is the code that converts this structure into a policy.  Mileage is going to vary.  The control parameters need to be adjusted based on your problem and your data.

```
# Define reinforcement learning parameters
control <- list(alpha = 0.2, gamma = 0.4, epsilon = 0.1)

# Perform reinforcement learning
model <- ReinforcementLearning(data = coins, 
                               s = "State", 
                               a = "Action", 
                               r = "Reward",
                               s_new = "NextState", 
                               iter = 10, 
                               control = control)

summary(model)

# Calculate optimal policy
pol <- computePolicy(model)
```

It takes a little while to run, but gives the following policy:

```
> print(pol)
110 111 010 011 100 101 000 001 
"h" "t" "t" "t" "h" "h" "h" "h"
```

So what does that mean?  How do we interpret it?

We thought we should get this:

1. (H), (H), (T) $\longrightarrow$ (H)
2. (H), (T), (H) $\longrightarrow$ (H)
3. (T), (H), (H) $\longrightarrow$ (T)

The above policy does this:

1. 110 $\longrightarrow$ "h"
2. 101 $\longrightarrow$ "h"
3. 011 $\longrightarrow$ "t"

So it estimated the policy for typical states, but also for non-mean but realized states.  We didn't plan for a "111" but the data had that, and our policy says we should predict the next case as a head.

Now you likely have an image of cats or dogs.  They are strings of binary inputs.  The fundamental problem with it is that your state is vastly larger than your number of samples.  You have a megapixel aka megabit image with a single classification.  To get number-of-samples equals number-of-unknowns you would need on the order of millions of training images.  The compute cost and memory cost for that is large.

What the first deep learning classifiers did was to convert an image of $224*224*3*8=1.2 * 10^6$ bits into a list of 1000 feature/location scores.  This is a compression that is much more than the order of 3 orders of magnitude in size.  It is moving the space from being $2^{1.2e6}$ discrete states, aka $10^{360e3}$ potential configurations, into a space that is 1000 continuous values.